# Position cursor to end of text of UITextView When changing the alignment of UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I position the cursor to the end of text in `UITextView`? When changing the alignment left,right and center need to change the cursor position to the end of the text in `UITextView`.

Can any one help me out?

I tried my luck, it's not working.

Comment: @ thanks for editing awoodland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [textView setContentOffset: textView.contentSize.height animated:NO]

Comment: CGPoint scrollPoint = editTextView.contentOffset;
   scrollPoint.y= scrollPoint.y+1;
   [editTextView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

I am using this. its working but.  when iam calling same function My y.axes is increasing .

Answer (score 1):

```
    CGPoint scrollPoint = editTextView.contentOffset;
        scrollPoint.y= scrollPoint.y - 0.0001f;
        [editTextView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
        scrollPoint.y = 0.0f;

I did had coding here. its working but cursor is moving after the text moved in the UITextView.

How to do both things once
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resigning the textView as first responder, then make it first responder right after that.

Example:

```
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[textView resignFirstResponder];
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Worked for me.